# Create a File Provider to the standard Download Directory on phone to send a PDF file via an Intent

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, android-fileprovider

When I pass it to a PDF viewer - it errors out and states it cannot open the file.
GoogleViewer prints the following in the log

```
2019-01-24 15:36:55.390 23756-23833/? V/LoadDocumentTask: Finish task: LoadDocumentTask(Display Data [PDF : mypdf.pdf] +ContentOpenable, uri: content://com.example.gregm.pdfplaygorund.provider/Download/Download/mypdf.pdf) result=FILE_ERROR time=16ms
```

The code that sends the intent

```
    String filepath = "storage/emulated/0/Download/mypdf.pdf";
            File file = new File(filepath);
            if(file.exists())
            {
                Log.e("ERRR", "file exists");
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",file);

         intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = MainActivity.this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                MainActivity.this.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            }

            startActivity(intent); // Crashes on this line
```

res/xml/provider_paths.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="Download" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Androidmanifest.xml

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.gregm.pdfplaygorund.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of having these in the manifest wasn't enough

I also had to request the permission

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ma,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                            MY_PERMISSIONS_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ma,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

Then the code above works